# Download an HTML file

Tags: html, file, download

I would like to create in my website (html/php) a link to download an HTML file without displaying this file in the navigator. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write a little PHP script, that forces the browser to download the file:

```
$fullPath = 'the/Path/To/The/File.html';

header('Content-Description: File Transfer'); 
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream'); 
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($fullPath)); 
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . basename($fullPath) . '"');
readfile($fullPath);
exit();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Naturaly, that work perfectly. Perhaps I asked too quickly my question, as if I was on a chat, but my troubles were relative to another detail of my code : When the wise man points at the moon, the idiot looks at the finger  :p